# Thymeleaf "th:each" ignores "th:switch"?

Tags: java, html, spring, thymeleaf

First I check if the item I get the tracklist from is a CD. If that's true I want to loop over the list and create a paragraph for each entry. My problem is that I will get an error at ${item.getTrackList()} for items that aren't a CD, because they don't have an attribute "trackList". Why is the "th:each" expression ignoring the switch-case statement?

```html
<div th:switch="${type}" th:remove="all-but-first">
    <div th:case="CD" th:each="track : ${item.getTrackList()}">
        <p th:text="${track}"></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#attribute-precedence

`th:each` is evaluated before `th:case`.  You're going to have to move it lower, something like this for example:

```
<div th:switch="${type}" th:remove="all-but-first">
  <th:block th:case="CD">
    <div th:each="track : ${item.trackList}">
      <p th:text="${track}"></p>
    </div>
  </th:block>
</div>
```

If you don't need the extra divs, something like:

```
<div th:switch="${type}" th:remove="all-but-first">
  <th:block th:case="CD">
    <p th:each="track : ${item.trackList}" th:text="${track}"></p>
  </th:block>
</div>
```